# Android - spinners inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, spinner

i have a `ListView` with a custom `Servizio` object in every row. I'm using `SimpleAdapter` for this and it's ok.

The problem is that i can't fill the spinner inside every `Servizio`. This code inside Servizio.java is causing my app to crash:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        int m = 3;//Integer.parseInt(camping.rulesList.getMaxPers().get(camping.tipSel));

        String[] array_spinner=new String[m];
        for (int indice = 0; indice < m; indice++)
        {
            if (indice == 0) array_spinner[indice] = String.format("%d persona", indice+1);
            else array_spinner[indice] = String.format("%d persone", indice+1);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(aa);
```

The same code is working for a single spinner on the main activity... what am i missing?

Thanks! ;-)

UPDATE: Here's the Log... Maybe the problem is that "Attempted to add window with non-application token WindowToken"...

> 01-11 16:23:06.038:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(12582): threadid=1:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40028a00) 01-11 16:23:06.038:
>   WARN/WindowManager(103): Attempted to
>   add window with non-application token
>   WindowToken{44ac0100 token=null}. 
>   Aborting. 01-11 16:23:06.058:
>   (...)

Comment: Please help me, i've stopped on this!

Comment: please post a stack trace, so we can see where the problem occured

Comment: You mean the LogCat Log?

Comment: can u please help me how you have achieved this task ? i am also faing problem i want to add spinner inside every listview row dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the problem was that i was using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`. And it didn't work 'till i've deleted **All** the `getApplicationContext()` of the class.