# Mimic the Overflow Spinner in a ListView Row

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put in a `Spinner` on each row of a `ListView` within a `ListFragment`.

I want it to look like a vertical overflow image like in the store but I'm not able to figure out how to show the vertical overflow image that is clickable to show the options.

[image]

It always looks like below instead. I would like to remove "Options" and have the overflow image instead.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656667/android-spinners-inside-a-listview

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, that describes having issues adding items to the `Spinner` which isn't my trouble. I am looking to mimic the overflow spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found relevant ideas from other posts and combined them, thank you Stack Overflow.

[Android: How to set spinner selector to own image/icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535109/android-how-to-set-spinner-selector-to-own-image-icon/5150999#5150999)

[Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)

[How to get width and height of the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552833/how-to-get-width-and-height-of-the-image)

The idea is that you create a 0dp width `Spinner` with an `ImageView` over it. When you click the image, it shows the drop down. I haven't tested it's behavior when the Spinner is at the edge of the screen yet and may very well cause trouble. I also need to tweak the position of the Spinner, but this works for now.

My plan is to catch the selection from the Spinner and then open a dialog / intent based on what was clicked. Here is what it looks like. (the ImageView is faint but it's mostly a placehodler for me right now)

**Before click**

[image]

**After click**

[image]

Here is the general code I used since this seems desirable to others.

**values/attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="OverflowSpinner">
        <attr name="imageResource" format="string" />
        <attr name="spinnerTextResource" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**values/strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="spinner_array">
        <item>Skip</item>
        <item>View log</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**layouts/row.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:awesome="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- stuff -->
    <com.blah.package.OverflowSpinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        awesome:imageResource="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
        awesome:spinnerTextResource="@array/spinner_array"
        /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OverflowSpinner.java**

```
public class OverflowSpinner extends RelativeLayout {
    int mImage;
    int mStrings;

    public OverflowSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public OverflowSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
        setupDisplay(context);
    }

    public OverflowSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
        setupDisplay(context);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) { 
        TypedArray attribs = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OverflowSpinner);
        // get attributes
        mImage = attribs.getResourceId(R.styleable.OverflowSpinner_imageResource, -1);
        mStrings = attribs.getResourceId(R.styleable.OverflowSpinner_spinnerTextResource, -1);

        attribs.recycle();
    }

    private void setupDisplay(Context context) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmap = (BitmapDrawable)this.getResources().getDrawable(mImage);
        int height = bitmap.getBitmap().getHeight();

    // set size of Spinner to 0 x height so it's "hidden"
    // the height is used to help position the Spinner in a nicer spot 
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, mStrings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // setup spinner
        final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(lp);
        this.addView(spinner);

        // set size of image to be normal
        lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        ImageButton option = new ImageButton(context);
        option.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        option.setImageResource(mImage);
        option.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // when clicking the image button, trigger the spinner to show
        option.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinner.performClick();
            }
        });
        this.addView(option);
    }
}
```